# Saved session value comes back empty

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I having home.html, login.html and logout.html

When a user clicks login and gets success, I store a session value. Then I come back to the home page and click logout.html. I am getting an empty session value. Please give me suggestion to fix this.

Login:

```php
<?php  
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
     session_start();
     header("Cache-control: private");
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $password = $_POST['pass'];
     if($email == 'dhaya')
     {
        $_SESSION['login_user']=  $email; 
        echo "success ";
     }
     else {
        echo "failer";
     }
```

Home:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   <body>
   <?php
if($_SESSION["user_name"]) {
?>
Welcome <?php session_start() echo $_SESSION['login_user']; ?>.
<?php
}
?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: "I having home.html, login.html and logout.html". These are supposed to have .php as extension.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` can't be called after any output has been sent to the browser.

To fix, move it to the top of your script.

You're also using `$_SESSION['user_name']` as well as `$_SESSION['login_user']` - assume this is a mistake, just use one of them.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   <body>
   <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['login_user'])) { ?>
       Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['login_user']; ?>.
   <?php } ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Use `session_destroy()`, and make it its own file e.g. logout.php, then redirect home again, e.g. `<?php session_start(); session_destroy(); header('Location: index.html');`

Comment: I also assume that you're using `.php` extensions whenever you have PHP code in your files, rather than `.html` (unless you've defined them as extensions that should be handled by PHP in your web server configuration)

Comment: Am new to php and html so am not having clear idea about what u saying. i will explain my side clearly pls help to fix. I am having the home.html file in that i am having menus as login,registartion and logout. so when user clicks on login.html page and click submit ,using angular am acessing my login.php and store session and then i came back to home page and click logout.html getting empty session even in home page also getting empty session.

Answer (score 0):

Session_start() has to be the first line of your php page before any output has been sent to the browser, otherwise it won't work. So right at the top of every page where you want to access the session, just have the `<?php session_start(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

> There is small mistake on your code. **You are missing `;` in your code**

```
Welcome <?php session_start()  echo $_SESSION['login_user']; ?>.
                             ^ missing ;
```